# Vlookup/Map value from one dataframe to another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do something similar to the vlookup in the python.
Here is a dataframe I want to lookup for value 'Flow_Rate_Lupa'[image]

And here is the dataframe I want to fill the data by looking at the same month+day to fill the missing value. Is there any one to help me to solve how to do this QAQ[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually merge the two data frames and define an indicator, then filter out the values where the indicator says both meaning data is in both data frames.

```
import pandas as pd

mergedData= pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left' ,left_on='Key1', right_on='Key2', indicator ='Exists')
filteredData = mergedData[mergedData[Exists]='both']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and the nreplace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove column:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['month','day'], how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
df['Flow_Rate_Lupa'] = df['Flow_Rate_Lupa'].fillna(df.pop('Flow_Rate_Lupa_'))
```